# Phylogenetic tree in R

Tags: r

I have read a paper saying about the phylogenomic supertree.

Does anyone know how to plot a phylogenetic tree showing order groups in the figure?

I am trying to learn more about this and in this case, I do not know what sort of data is appropriate

It would be appreciative if anyone could give a solution for this[image]

**Updated**:

I would like to give you guys my trying for this stuff.

So far, I got stuck in how to plot Family/Order of species on tips of the tree.

For everything that I know so far, I could plot the phylogenetic trees at species level like the figure here.

I use `ggTree` package for visualization.

I was thinking that I might add manually Family or Order levels into the tree by following the internal nodes between 2 different genera. But it seems to be inappropriate to get the figure that I want.

Does anyone know something about this case?

[image]

Comment: I don't know where you can get the tree data from, but the [phylogenetics task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Phylogenetics.html) includes a section on plotting phylogenies. The [figtree](http://tree.bio.ed.ac.uk/software/figtree/) software package (outside of R) is good for plotting.

Comment: Hi, I am doing the bird data from https://birdtree.org/. I was trying to use `phylo` or `ggtree` packages, but they didnt work. Thanks for your advice. I will check it out.

Comment: If there is something specific you are already trying, please give us a [mcve]: show us what you're doing and explain **specifically** what's not working/what's unsatisfactory about the results.

Comment: https://epirhandbook.com/phylogenetic-trees-1.html

Comment: `phangorn (version 2.5.5)`, superTree: Super Tree methodsPhylogenomic supertree. See here <https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/phangorn/versions/2.5.5/topics/superTree>

Comment: does the taxonomy file https://data.vertlife.org/birdtree/BLIOCPhyloMasterTax.csv from birdtrees have the groupings you're interested in?

Comment: @BenBolker yes, I am using the global tree from Jetz.